# How to get response-header from curl post request?

Tags: php, curl

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'PortalPartner' . ":" . 'W169F1320&8d');

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$header = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I need to see the response header where is will be token for my next request, but I can not. 
When I use this request in insomnia or postman I can see response header but I can not in code.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a callback function for headers using [`curl_setopt`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) with `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION`. The callback will be execute for each header line.

```php
$headers=[];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, function($ch, $header) use ($headers){
    array_push($headers, $header);
});
```

Note that this will be executed for every header line including the initial `HTTP/` line and will be provided with a simple string. You will need to split each line on ":" to separate the key and value. Typically, I would parse the headers into an associative array.